# pivoting/formatting SQL select statement output

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL tables in Oracle

```
EVENT
event_id        event_name
----------------------------
001                A
002                B
003                C
004                D
005                E
006                F

EVENTOCCURENCE
datetime            event_id
-------------------------------
21-06-2019            A
16-03-2019            C
10-02-2019            A
02-01-2019            B
13-09-2019            A
27-02-2019            C
04-06-2019            A
09-01-2019            B
```

I want to retrieve an output which looks like this

```
event_id        no_of_occurences        Jan    Feb    Mar ....
------------------------------------------------------------
A                    4                   0      1      0
B                    2                   2      0      0
C                    2                   0      1      1
D                    0                   0      0      0
E                    0                   0      0      0
F                    0                   0      0      0
```

I have aggregated the data as follows

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
         event left
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            to_char(datetime, 'Month'),
            event_id,
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            eventoccurence
        GROUP BY
            event_id,
            to_char(datetime, 'Month')
    ) o
    ON event.dem_code = o.dem_code;
```

But am unsure how to format it to retrieve the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PIVOT`

```
        Select * from   (  SELECT
        to_char(datetime, 'Month') as mnth,
        event_id,
        COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM
        eventoccurence
    GROUP BY
        event_id,
        to_char(datetime, 'Month')
     ) 
      Pivot
     (
      Max(cnt) 
     for TO_CHAR(mnth,'MON') in 
      ('JAN','FEB',.....,'DEC'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `PIVOT` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT E.EVENT_NAME, TO_CHAR(EO.DATETIME,'MON') AS MON 
   FROM EVENT E LEFT JOIN EVENTOCCURENCE EO
     ON E.EVENT_ID = EO.EVENT_ID)
PIVOT (COUNT(1) AS NO_OF_OCCURANCES 
       FOR MON IN ('JAN' AS JAN, 'FEB' AS FEB ..... 'DEC' AS DEC))
```

**-- Update**

For `TOTAL`, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT E.EVENT_NAME, TO_CHAR(EO.DATETIME,'MON') AS MON 
   FROM EVENT E LEFT JOIN EVENTOCCURENCE EO
     ON E.EVENT_ID = EO.EVENT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT E.EVENT_NAME, 'TOTAL' AS MON 
   FROM EVENT E LEFT JOIN EVENTOCCURENCE EO
     ON E.EVENT_ID = EO.EVENT_ID )
PIVOT (COUNT(1) AS NO_OF_OCCURANCES 
       FOR MON IN ('JAN' AS JAN, 'FEB' AS FEB ..... 'DEC' AS DEC, 'TOTAL' AS TOTAL))
```

Comment: I however want to include all the events in the output, even though there is no occurrence related to it. And also include a column of total counts of occurrences for each event.

Comment: How do I also add a total column to this? With the total occurrences of each event in all months?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT event_id, COUNT(*) as num_occurrences,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(datetime, 'MON') = 'JAN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as jan,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(datetime, 'MON') = 'FEB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as feb,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(datetime, 'MON') = 'MAR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as mar,
       . . .
FROM eventoccurence
GROUP BY event_id;
```

Note that this includes the total number of occurrences.  Also, I suspect that you want a restriction on the year, but I haven't included it.

Pivot is quite limited in its functionality.  I don't know why Oracle bothered including it, given that it is not standard.